# cordova 5.0.0 is not generating apk file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova 5.0.0 and ionic 2.2.3. I want to develop the android apk file. 
ihave used 
`cordova build --release`
But i cannot find any apk files.
In my project folder not found build folder in this path `projectname\platforms\android`

I want to know how to generate apk file and where did fro i get the file.

Comment: ionic build android

Comment: The command is working but not building apk file. Or i am not seeing any apk file. so please help me.

Comment: try to install directly to mobile. connect your mobile, enable debugging mode in mobile, then run a command 'ionic run android'

Comment: not running in mobile also.

Comment: After successful built the apk path is shown at the very last line in CLI, which is 'platform/android/build/outputs/apk/'

Comment: @Deepika /build/outputs/apk/ is not found. That's my problem plaese help me.

Comment: did you get build successful after the 'ionic build android' comand?

Comment: @Deepika it sucessfully but not run in emulator. I am using windows 10.

Comment: post the console log you are getting when you run the above command

Comment: @Joe did you found any solution? because i am facing the same issue now with ionic 3.12.0. I am using ionic daily from last 3 months but suddenly today i am facing the problem. Strange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just run the command 
ionic cordova build android.

it will itself create the .apk file in your platforms/andriod folder.

Comment: This is obviously what we are trying to do, but not working